# Raster Calculator not excluding 0 values (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am using QGIS 3.10.2 and attempting to mask out `0` values with the Raster Calculator. I have a series of values from `0` to `255`, with `0` being empty space on the boundaries that I do not care about. My equation in the Raster Calculator is as follows:

`("a">0)*"a"`

Where `"a"` is the raster layer I am trying to mask. However, the output gives me the same raster, with `0` values still included. Can anyone shed some insight on this problem?

I am new to QGIS.

Comment: Each pixel must have some value. What value would you like to give for the values which are currently 0? Or do you actually want to label pixels with value 0 as nodata into the image metadata?

Comment: I suppose I would like to label the pixels with value 0 as nodata. Is there an equivalent to the Raster "Extract by Attribute" tool in Arc?

Comment: You can find the controls for nodata in QGIS from the layer properties - Transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of all 0 value cells, open the layer properties, select the "Transparency" tab, make sure No data value is checked and type in 0 as "Additional no data value"

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much.